# Definition of $\omega$-inconsistency

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I am currently studying Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems, and I have a question about $\omega$-inconsistency.

Some say that a theory $T$ is $ω$-inconsistent if $T$ proves $P(0)$, $P(1)$, $P(2)$,... and also proves that there is a number $N$ for which $P(N)$ fails.

Others instead say that $T$ is $\omega$-inconsistent if it proves that there is a number for which $P(N)$ holds, but proves that $P(0)$ fails, $P(1)$ fails,...

Which one is wrong? Or (as I think) are they equivalent?

Comment: Both definitions should say "... for some formula $P(n)$ ". You can then see that they are equivalent by switching $P(n)$ and $\lnot P(n)$

Comment: There are two notions, $\omega$-consistency and $\Omega$-consistency. They are *entirely* different. Pick one.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I think you need to say something more about $\Omega$-(in)consistency to make your comment helpful. I think the OP is only concerned with $\omega$-(in)consistency and has made a typo (that you find very significant) in the title.

Comment: @Rob: $\Omega$-logic is due to Woodin and involves universally Baire sets and large cardinals. It's entirely different from $\omega$-consistency and so on. Mathematics is case-sensitive.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: thanks for explaining your comment in sufficient detail to make it clear to all that it was irrelevant to the question as stated. As the OP may now be unlikely to feel confident enough to do so, I have fixed the (to you) all-important typo in the capitalisation of the Greek letter in the title.

Answer (score 1):

*Turning Rob Arthan's initial comment into an answer to kick this off the "unanswered" queue, and CW-ifying to avoid reputation gain for someone else's work*:

The two definitions are equivalent: given one, we get the other by swapping $P$ and $\neg P$. (This reveals an omitted clause in the definitions: we need to begin with "**for some $P$**" There's no single $P$ which "tests for $\omega$-inconsistency.")